# What's up being a Mayor?

Tags: watch-dogs

I've been under a rock for some time and just bought Watch_Dogs. I'm intrigued about the perks of being a mayor after checking in at some hotspots.

My questions are:

1. How exactly do you become mayor for a particular location?
2. What perks of being a mayor?
3. Is being a mayor only temporary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To become mayor for a particular hotspot, you must check in at that location more times over a seven day period than any other player. You will remain mayor for a particular location while you remain the most frequent visitor.

Being mayor is primarily about collecting badges and achievements, however you will get to collect any goodies left behind when you're checking in.

Comment: so there will be like some loots like electric devices or such? and  how many days are you gonna be mayor?

Comment: Yes - items and cash are left at hotspots and can be picked up by any visitor. You will remain mayor while you're the #1 visitor for a particular hotspot.

Comment: I've been at the same spots 9 times over a few days - it says there are no mayors at these locations - when does mayorship pop?